# Submit a new site description into Google

Tags: search-engine-indexing

Google indexed my site in a moment where I had the wrong content, and the search results currently show a "Loren Ipsun" text as my site description.

How can I re-submit the description of my site to overwrite the one currently indexed by Google?

Comment: Just changing it (or creating it if it doesn't exist) and wait ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Google does not visit your website only once. They do it on regular basis. 
So after a while it should fix itself. But it takes time. To be on a safer side, update your website and add the URL for recrawling.

How to request a recrawl: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en.

Submitting the webpage to Google's index: http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/website-owner/